# Travelling Salesman Problem Variation repeated visits and outside cities visit

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman

**Problem**. Given a directed weighted graph G(V, E), **not necessarily completed**,
find the shortest path going over each city in the given cities set (a vertices subset of V),
we can repeat each city more than once, and we are allowed to visit cities **that are not** in the cities set but are on the graph.

Now, I know that there is a TSP version when we are allowed to repeat the visit of the inner vertices,
however, in this problem, we can actually visit outsider's vertices.

For example:

```
V={0,1,2,...10} and E is unknown, we have the cities set {0,1,3,8,9}
```

so the following path:

```
8 -> 9 -> 0 -> 3 -> 9 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 1
```

is valid, and needs to be taken the path into consideration in the algorithm.

Now, I have to be able to have the algorithm running with an enormous number of vertices, like 1000000,
so I know that the algorithm should be a greedy one, but  I don't know how to approach it
with an efficient way of following these requirements.

Comment: The potential solutions are well-documented already. I assume you've read the entire [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)? "*I don't know how to approach it*" is not a valid excuse when there is so much information out there already.

Comment: @ATB The first step in a lot of programming problems (in industry or in school) is usually to search for similar problems and ideas.  Often you will learn more, faster, and arrive at a better solution after doing this research.  The second step is to rewrite the answer, as if you are programming it for the first time, because copying the code into your solution means you copy assumptions that might be wrong for your needs and it also means you're copying the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the distances between cities are reasonable, that is the direct distance between A and B is always shorter than the distance A -> C -> B ( i.e. real world distances rather than logical distances ) then million node graphs can be dealt with in reasonable time frames.

This means, nothing like this:

[image]

You do need to define what you consider a reasonable time frame before we can discuss this further.

I would use C++ for such problems.

For a brief discussion of the sort of time performance that can be expected on a graph containing half a million nodes: https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Performance

Comment: First of all thank you very much, nothing so I understood how the first paragraph relates to what I asked? As for reasonable time I was happy for the time, I could run tests and not wait a few hours or long minutes.
The distances are not related to the real world. They are very random.

Comment: The language I use is JAVA only, in addition, I searched for a solution for the problem and found that the idea is to start from a random vertex and choose a random order of the vertices to go through, and move in order for each pair of vertices in order is considered the shortest way and thus do to the destination.
I'm not sure how effective it is and if it works.

Comment: A word of warning:  the algorithm you mention will take many days to complete an a graph with a million nodes.  I take it that you consider 1 minute the maximum time to completion you would accept.  Even with a sophisticated algorithm and a high performance language, that is going to be a challenge!

Comment: An interpreted language ( such as JAVA ) is never going to provide the performance you are looking for.

Comment: Ok thanks,  i  don't  want a maximum time performance its okay to be  like a 1 hour

Comment: there are any clue about my question?

Comment: If the distances between your "cities" do not satisfy the triangle inequality ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Metric ) then the problem is NP hard and a million node network is intractable.

Comment: I know is NP-hard I don't want it to be 100% accurate but it's okay to apply a greedy algorithm etc...

Comment: Do you understand the triangle inequality?  Are you certain your cities do not satisfy it?

Comment: Yes, the cities do not satisfy it, the number of edges is a real number and random.

Comment: You do not understand the triangle inequality.  It has nothing to do with the number of edges.  Please read the link I provided.

Comment: "the number of edges is a real number"  What does this mean?  The number of edges is always integer.  A fraction of an edge has no meaning.  Two vertices are linked or they are not!

Comment: I mean the value of the edges are real number and random,  the weight of the edges ****

Comment: It only matters that the total A->C->B is greater than A->B.

Comment: the weight  of  the edges is always positive but, the value is very random so it's not correct there are chances that are A->B  smallest then A->C->B

Comment: Provide an example where A->C->B is smaller than A->B where all -> are +ve.

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/S2ocI there is an example

Comment: Good example.  Your problem is intractable.

Comment: if this problem is intractable so how Dijkstra algorithm works on our givens?

Comment: The Dijkstra algorithm is much, much easier than the travelling salesman problem on a non-metric graph.

Comment: there is no problem that the travelling salesman problem will be not accurate I just want the greedy algorithm for that.